# Data filter grid in angular

Tags: angular

[image]

When I click on any colour above, the grid filters those colours, how can I do this in angular? Please suggest me any npm package for it in angular

Answer (score 2):

I would assume each object in the grid has a color property. When clicking on a color you can filter the array of grid objects.

Html:

```
<button (click)="filterGridObjects('green')">Filter on green</button>
<div *ngFor="let object of gridObjects">
...
</div>
```

Component:

```
filterGridObjects(color: string) {
  this.gridObjects = this.objects.filter(object => object.color === color)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to provide some context to what you are trying to achieve, though you can do it your self in a relatively simple approach..

define an array to store the cards

```
  cardsArr: any[];
```

define a color filter property that update according to the selected color filter

```
selectedColorFilter: string;
```

define a filtering method

```
// component.ts

public getCardsByFilter(): any[] {
    if (!this.selectedColorFilter)
        return this.cardsArr;
    else {
       return this.cardsArr.filter(/* you filtering logic here based on color code*/ )
   }
}
```

finally use the filter in your template

```
// template.html
<div *ngFor="let card of getCardsByFilter()">
    <card-component [card]="card"></card-component> 
</div>
```